# 404 Not Found JSON file Liferay

Tags: javascript, json, liferay

everything goes well in a regular HTML page, but with the same code used in a liferay portlet,I have this problem:

**GET http://localhost:8080/web/guest/data/myfile.json 404 (Not Found) index.js:103**

This is the code:

```
function loadFiles(){

    loadJSONNetworkInventory(function(response) {

        parsedMyFile = JSON.parse(response);

    });
}


function loadJSONNetworkInventory(callback) {   

    var xobjNI = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobjNI.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobjNI.open('GET', 'data/myfile.json', false); 
    xobjNI.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xobjNI.readyState == 4 && xobjNI.status == "200") {
            callback(xobjNI.responseText);
        }
    };
    xobjNI.send(null);  
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `<%=request.getContextPath()%>/data/myfile.json`?

Comment: Yes, but this is the error:
 GET http://localhost:8080/web/guest/%3C%=request.getContextPath()%%3E/data/myfile.json 400 (Bad Request)  index.js:103

Comment: First create a `data` folder at the root of your portlet, place your `JSON` file there then use this path `/data/myfile.json`.

Comment: Complete URL should be like `http://localhost:8080/your-portlet/data/myfile.json`

Comment: Thank you, using the entire url it works.

Comment: I meant to say `<%=request.getContextPath() %>/data/myfile.json`, this should be your path.

Comment: If I use this I have as result: error: GET localhost:8080/web/guest/%3C%=request.getContextPath()%%3E/data/… 400 (Bad Request) index.js:103

Comment: Who has asked you to use `/web/guest/...`? Check, what URL does `<%=request.getContextPath() %>/data/myfile.json` generate, it will be like `/your-portlet/data/myfile.json` and that is sufficient to locate the resource.

Comment: When I excute the portlet Liferay automatically puts web/guest. In my code I have wrote the above url.

Comment: And what about when using like `/your-portlet/data/myfile.json`?

Comment: I have tried only http://localhost:8080/your-portlet/data/myfile.json and now it works.

Comment: Does it work like this? `<%=request.getContextPath()%>+"/data/myfile.json"`

Comment: Are you using javascript from external file?

Comment: @SASM no, among the solutions that you prosed me the only that works is to use the whole url "http://localhost:8080/portlet-name/data/myfile.json". This loads my json file and displays the data in the right way ..

Comment: @ParkashKumar yes, I use an external file..

Comment: @Heisenberg, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure, how do you assume that the URL
>   `http://localhost:8080/web/guest/data/myfile.json` will serve you
>   `myfile.json` as response when called. Where do you construct that URL
>   and how do you suppose it to work?

Well, the other simple way around is that you create the `data` folder under the `docroot` of your portlet and move your `myfile.json` file there.

Now just above the include of your external javascript file (of which you have shared some code), add following lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var portletContextPath = '<%=request.getContextPath() %>';
</script>
```

And make following changes in your given script:

```
function loadJSONNetworkInventory(callback) {
    var xobjNI = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobjNI.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    var jsonFilePath = portletContextPath + '/data/myfile.json';
    xobjNI.open('GET', jsonFilePath, false); 
    xobjNI.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xobjNI.readyState == 4 && xobjNI.status == "200") {
            callback(xobjNI.responseText);
        }
    };

    xobjNI.send(null);
}
```

That's it! `portletContextPath` will be serving as javascript variable to get dynamic context path of your portlet and `jsonFilePath` will be the path of your `myfile.json`.

Comment: Thanks, first of all thanks for your explanation.. the url that works fine is localhost:8080/portlet-name/data/myfile.json", as i have wrote above, and not http://localhost:8080/web/guest/data/myfile.json as you have wrote.. they are different, in fact the second one does not work..

Comment: So, leave the top, do as suggested. `var jsonFilePath = portletContextPath + '/data/myfile.json';` will be exactly as `/portlet-name/data/myfile.json`

Answer (score 0):

Try this on web.config

```
<system.webServer>
 <staticContent>
  <mimeMap  fileExtension=".json" mimeType="text/json" />
 </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```